# Next Js 13 API route not getting the correct data after post request

Tags: javascript, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am working on an authentication project with Django backend and Next js frontend. I am using redux toolkit for state management and I am having a problem with working on the next js api which sends data to the backend.
Here is my actions on auth.js which sends the data to the API:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
    });
    // alert(`body is ${body}`) //This alert is showing data hence it`s working
    dispatch({
        type: SET_AUTH_LOADING
    });
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/auth/login/api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: body
        });
    } catch (error) {

    }
}
```

And here is my API route which is supposed to communicate with the backend:

```
export async function POST(request) {
    const res = await request.body;
    console.log (`Response is ${res}`)
    const { email, password } = await request.body;
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
    });
    console.log(`Posted data is: ${body}`)
    return NextResponse.json({ res })
}
```

The first `console.log` returns `Response is [object Object]` and then the second `console.log` returns `Posted data is: {}`. I am unable to figure out what could be the problem since the API route is being called.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: well, for one thing, you submit `email` but then try to get `username`, which won't exist

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I edited the code but still got the same results

Comment: have you changed the `config` on server from the default at all? By default, you should be able tog get body w/o awaiting it, but if it changed, you might need to access rawBody

Comment: I have not changed the `config` at all

Comment: oic. you need to await the request.json(), not the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next.js 13 changed some things. For JSON content, you invoke `.json` method and await it

```
export async function POST(request) {
    const body = await request.json();

    const { email, password } = body;
    const bodystring = JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
    });
    console.log(`Posted data is: ${bodystring}`);
    return NextResponse.json({ res: body });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the console is working let me continue with the rest of the code